# import java.util.Scanner sc error

Tags: java

Can some one help me with an error with my Java code?

```
import java.util.Scanner sc = new
java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

This gives the error

```
import java.util.Scanner sc = new
                         ^
```

What's wrong with the `sc`?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `import` in

```
import java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: when i remove the import like this "java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);" just same , the error message need class or interface expected.

Comment: It should work unless you forgot to wrap your code in a class.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly import scanner use:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

to create a new scanner as a variable do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This will create a new scanner named `sc`.

Comment: you mean we make 2 like this ? "import java.util.Scanner;" and below that make again "Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);" that you mean ? but still no change.